# loopback operation hook: add filter to count api

Tags: loopbackjs

I need to intercept my loopback queries before they query my Mongodb to add additional filters, for example, to limit the object to what the user has access to.

I can successfully update the query on access operation hook to add filters to the GET /Applications , where Applications is my object. However This fails to work for GET /Applications/count

The command runs with a 200, however it returns zero results, even though I'm adding the exact same filters.  There most be something different about count that I'm missing. The ctx object looks have a ton of functions/objects in it. I'm only touching the query property, but there must be something else I need to do.

Any ideas? Thank you, Dan

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your `access` hook observer's implementation. I tried it on a sample app, and following `access` hook works as expected for `/api/Books/count`:

```
module.exports = function(Book) {
      Book.observe('access', function logQuery(ctx, next) {
        ctx.query.where.id = 2; // changing filter value for where
      console.log('Accessing %s matching %j', ctx.Model.modelName, ctx.query.where);
      next();
    });
};
```

Verify that you're modifying `query` property of Context (see [access hook](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Operation-hooks.html#access)).
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I've got sidetracked on a few other items in the last few days.  I'll try your example.